# Join two anchor points to same line path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, pen-tool

I've created very basic shape with Illustrator CS6. here's my shape

[image: Basic shape]

My first anchor point on inner shape (no. 1) successfully join the line path (on left side). But not with the second one. No.2 cannot join the line path on left side.

How to join the anchor point no.2 to line path? I want fill the inner shape with outer shape with different color. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oviously you had the outer shape ready when you tried to draw the inner shape starting from point 1. and stopped at point2. Your problem = 1 and 2 are perfectly on the curve of the outer shape, but you cannot get fill of the inner shape to exactly fit to the original curve of the outer shape.

Your original goal can be read "join paths to make branches". It's not solvable in Illustrator. Paths do not have branches.

Solve the fit and color problem otherwise:

- Select all
- take the shape builder tool and
- click the areas that you want to be separately fillable.

The tool builds exactly fitting closed shapes for you:

[image]

In the left the bigger area is just clicked with the shape builder tool. In the right both have got their fills with ordinary fill color selection.

The endpoints 1 and 2 need not to be exactly on the curve, they can be more to left, the tool works also with crossings. You must manually remove the remnants.

Here all were selected, the inner shape interior only is clicked with the shape builder, the areas are colored and finally all are moved apart only to show what we have:

[image]

The shape builder tool separated the clicked area from the already closed outer shape.

You may have a reason to keep the outer shape intact (transparency, need to make copies later). Then make a copy before building the shapes. Learn to use the layers panel to control what is selected and what's not.

Answer (score 1):

- If they are 2 open paths:

  - select both points with the white arrow (Direct selection)
  - Right-click / Average
  - Right-click / Join

However I am not sure I understand your shape, as it seems to me that point 2 would have 3 lines, which of course would not work. You can only join 2 **open** paths.

Do you get an error message when you try to join them?